# PHP: Two buttons to submit

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I've been trying to submit two buttons, one to delete and one to edit/add. But I can't seem to get it right.

HTML:

```
    <!-- Edit/Delete Account Form -->
        <form method="get" action="edit.php" onsubmit="setTimeout('location.reload()');">
          <div id="edit-form" class="modal hide fade">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                        <h4><?php _e('Edit/Delete Account'); ?></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div id="message"></div>
                            <div class="control">
                <div id="edit-account-form">
    <table id="add-account" class="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td valign="middle">
            Account Number
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="hidden" id="editid" name="editid" value=""/>
            <input type="text" id="number" name="number" value="Enter Some text here "/>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
            Account Description
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="text" id="description" name="description" value="Enter Some text here "/>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
            Level 01
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="text" id="level01" name="level01" value="Enter Some text here "/>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
            Level 02
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="text" id="level02" name="level02" value="Enter Some text here "/>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
            Level 03
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="text" id="level03" name="level03" value="Enter Some text here "/>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
            Level 04
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="text" id="level04" name="level04" value="Enter Some text here "/>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
            Tax
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="text" name="account" value="Enter Some text here "/>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
            Allow General Journals
            </td>
            <td>
            <select>
            <option selected disabled>Select</option>
            <option>Yes</option>
            <option>No</option>
            </select>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
            Allow Payments
            </td>
            <td>
            <select>Select</select>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
            Allow Expense Claims
            </td>
            <td>
            <select>Select</select>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
            Show On Dashboard
            </td>
            <td>
            <select>Select</select>
            </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" data-complete-text="<?php _e('Done'); ?>" name="add" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><?php _e('Submit'); ?></button>
                        <p class="pull-left"><button type="submit" name="delete" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><?php _e('Delete'); ?></button></p>

                    </div>
                </div>
        </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

    //Account Details
    $number = $_GET['number'];
    $description = $_GET['description'];
    $level01 = $_GET['level01'];
    $level02 = $_GET['level02'];
    $level03 = $_GET['level03'];
    $level04 = $_GET['level04'];
    $id = $_GET['editid'];

    $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'accounting') or die('Connection error!');

    if(isset($_POST['delete'])) { 
     $check = "DELETE FROM accountSlave WHERE `id` = '$id' ";
     mysqli_query($dbc, $check) or die('Database error, delete account!');
     }
    if(isset($_POST['add'])) {      
     //$check = "DELETE FROM accountSlave WHERE `id` = '$id' ";
    $check = "UPDATE accountSlave SET `accountNumber` = '$number', `accountDescription` = '$description', `accountLevel1` = '$level01', `accountLevel2` = '$level02', `accountLevel3` = '$level03', `accountLevel4` = '$level04' WHERE `id` = '$id'";
     mysqli_query($dbc, $check) or die('Database error, add account!');
     }

    header('location:master-accounts.php');

?>
```

It works when I have one query. I've tried one query to add and to delete and it worked. But I need to submit a delete if delete button clicked and vice versa.

I followed this post to try get it right [multiple buttons on a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120678/multiple-buttons-on-a-form)

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: use if and else if once and check its not post its get

Comment: Please -- wherever you got the idea of this code from -- **RUN** away from it.  It is open to [SQL Injection Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  Any new code written today should be using [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: Thank you @JeremyJStarcher for pointing this out. This is just for testing purposes until the site goes live.

Comment: @msbodetti -- Testing code has a bad habit of sticking around for a long time.i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`. It should be like

```
if(isset($_GET['delete'])) {
```

and

```
if(isset($_GET['add'])) {
```

Because your form submit method is `GET` not the `POST`

Comment: OMW thank you soo much! Didn't catch on when I just copied it from the other post :) Will accept your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You have to check which button is pressed and according to that do your operation.

Also you have to use `$_GET` not `$_POST` because your `form method` is `GET`.

```
if(isset($_GET['add'])) {
    // code for add
} elseif(isset($_GET['delete'])) {
    // code for delete
}
```