# How to use multiple buttons in a single form with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm trying to make a form that allows me to NAVIGATE/INSERT/MODIFY/DELETE entries in a database.

To apply the corresponding queries (insert, modify and delete) I would like to use simple HTML buttons at the bottom of the form.

My question is would it be possible to have each button calling a different query?  Any suggestion on how to do this in a simple way as I'm a beginner.

Comment: Give each button a different name, and see if if there's a corresponding $_GET/$_POST variable set. Perform a different query depending on which one was set

Comment: indeed ,as MLeFevre said, you can go in this way.. Or, eventually, you can perform dynamic ajax requests and sanitize the query on the server side before performing it.

Comment: Assuming this is a POST form: When you handle the action of this form, temporarily use `print_r($_POST)` to see how the name of the clicked submit button is added.

Comment: Yes, you can do that easily. It's answered here pretty nicely: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120678/multiple-buttons-on-a-form

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

**PHP**

```
$do_action = null;
if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {
    // Do Insert
    $do_action = 'Insert';
} elseif (isset($_POST['modify'])) {
    // Do Modify
    $do_action = 'Modify';
} elseif (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    // Do Delete
    $do_action = 'Delete';
} elseif (isset($_POST['navigate'])) {
    // Do Navigate
    $do_action = 'Navigation';
}

if ($do_action != null) {
    echo 'The last action performed was : <strong>' . $do_action . '</strong>';
    // After performing the action, you should redirect the user, so they cannot Refresh the page/press F5 to re-submit the form by mistake
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Insert">
    <input type="submit" name="modify" value="Modify">
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">
    <input type="submit" name="navigate" value="Navigate">
</form>
```

As I've commented, after you've performed your query, make sure to redirect your user somewhere sensible so they cannot accidentally Refresh the page and submit the same query again.

Comment: Thank you, MLeFevre. I didn't know it was possible to identify which submit button was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
{
//INSERT QUERY 
}
if(isset($_POST['submit2']))
{
//DELETE QUERY 
}
if(isset($_POST['submit3']))
{
//UPDATE QUERY 
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, Sameer. As I said, I didn't know this was possible.

Comment: You Welcome Mr. @Geoff