# How to get selected checkbox ID from some checkboxes in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, checkbox, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm creating some checkboxes in my laravel view as shown below :

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover">
   <tr>
     <th>Report</th>
     <th>Type</th>
     <th>Date</th>
  </tr>
 @foreach($tableContent as $data)
  <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="report" value="reportValue" id="{{$data->id}}" >{{$data->title}} </input></td>
  <td><b>{{$data->report_type}}</b></td>
  <td>{{$data->created_at}}</td>
  </tr>
 @endforeach
 </table>
<a class="btn btn-default" href="/deletereport/"{{--how do I get checked box id here ? --}}">Delete</a>
```

So when user click the delete button, it will gonna call the route /deletereport/idcheckedbutton...

But I have no idea how do I get the selected button Id, Please help...:v

Thanks in advance.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are trying to delete every line that the user checked. If your checkboxes are inside a form element you don't need to pass the id in the url, the checked values will be available in your `$request` object.

Then you have to change your checkbox name to

```
<input type="checkbox" name="reports[{{$data->id}}]" value="reportValue" id="{{$data->id}}" >{{$data->title}}</input>
```

Then you can access this array in your controller.

```
$reports = $request->input('reports');
```

The array will look something like this:

```
[
    0 => 34 // the '0' is the $data->id and the '34' is the value assigned to the input
]
```

I have not been able to test this yet so let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: okie... Thanks a lot Mr. Kevin.. I will try it this night.. :)

Comment: I'm trying it rightnow Mr. Kevin, but I'm confused about the form that I have to put together with my checkbox. I mean how to connect my form to my delete button...???

Comment: I'm making it like this :
<form action="/deletereport" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
                      <td><input type="checkbox" name="reports[{{$data->id}}]"  id="{{$data->id}}" >{{$data->title}} </input></td>
                    </form>

Comment: I'm confused about calling my controller route.. because if log::info($request); it gives me an empty log...

Comment: You can trigger the submit event on the form via javascript or you can turn your link into a submit button. If you choose the button, make sure the button is inside the form you are trying to submit. Also, in your function you declare the $request variable like so: functionName(Request $request). Make sure your form is outside your for-loop otherwise you will have multiple forms.

Comment: mmm...... there are some button beside "delete" button...so I'm confused which one will be triggered...

Comment: A submit button will trigger the form action so in your case you can't use my solution. You can add a name and value to your button. You can check this answer on how to handle multiple buttons in your form http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120678/multiple-buttons-on-a-form. If you still need help, let me know.

Comment: Ooowh... okie... Thanks a lot Mr. Kevin, Lemme take a look at the link... :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JavaScript for this. In the onclick event of the button, just get the checked checkbox and redirect to the edited url:

```
$('a.btn').click(function()
{
    location.href = $(this).attr('href') + $('input[name="report"]:checked').attr('id');
});
```

*Note that I'm using jQuery library.*

Comment: I prefer using pure php for now Mr. Martin... :) Is there a way for using php...?? :)