# Using POST with multiple buttons on a form with CppCMS

Tags: c++, post, model-view-controller, cppcms

I am following this CppCMS [tutorial](http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/cppcms_1x_forms) along with its [sample code](http://cppcms.com/cppcms_ref/latest/ex_forms.html).  There is a single button in the form, and the template contains something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="" >
```

1. How can you use POST with multiple buttons on a form to do different things?
2. How can you design the layout, sizing, coloring, background color for different buttons with CppCMS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple buttons on a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120678/multiple-buttons-on-a-form)

Comment: This is not purely a cppcms question, but more of HTML one. Also, please only ask one question at a time.

Comment: Regarding your second question: What are your problems. What have you tried so far? I recommend you to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) because your question(s) tends to lack some important aspects.

Comment: @hellow, thank you for replying.  I was trying to do it in C++ with CppCMS so I am not sure if your suggested answer would work.  As for the second question, it seems that CppCMS offers no customization for its buttons (cppcms::widgets::submit class).